# Pre-install and post-install advice for installing Ubuntu 12.10 before installing folding@home

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation, foldingathome

Machine specs:

- Intel S5520SC workstation board with dual Intel X5570 Hyperthreaded Quad core
- 24GB Unbuffered DDR3
- 320GB WD HD
- 2 X ATI HD 5770 GPU

I have prepared a bootable USB key with ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64 which I have tested prior to attempting to install the OS.

Is there anything else that I need to do before and/or after installing the OS in order to install the [folding@home app](https://foldingathome.org/start-folding/?lng=en-US) for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

As dumb as it may sound, make sure you have a power supply and case. Your power supply must adhere to the amounts of watts your motherboard, processor, and other supplies require. Also make sure you have all the chords to connect all your supplies to your power supply. *(not gonna go far without that...)* Otherwise, you look pretty good to go besides a screen, keyboard, and display.